# How to minimize the amount of boilerplate when using the `num::Float` trait and interacting with primitive types in Rust

Tags: rust

Is there a good methodology for minimizing the amount of boilerplate when using the `num::Float` trait and interacting with primitive types in Rust?  As an example, consider a poorly written quadratic equation solver

```
// External libraries
use num::Float;

// Poorly written quadratic formula solver for a x^2 + bx + c
fn myquad <Real> (a : Real, b : Real, c : Real) -> Option<(Real,Real)>
where
    Real : Float
{
    let mysqrt = Real::sqrt(b.powi(2)-Real::from(4.0)?*a*c);
    let r1 = (-b+mysqrt)/(Real::from(2.0)?*a);
    let r2 = (-b-mysqrt)/(Real::from(2.0)?*a);
    Some((r1,r2))
}

// Write a couple of tests
fn main() {
    let r1 = myquad::<f32> (1.0,1.0,-6.0).unwrap();
    println!("Roots of (x-2) (x+3):  ({},{})",r1.0,r1.1);
    let r2 = myquad::<f64> (6.0,5.0,-4.0).unwrap();
    println!("Roots of (2x-1) (3x+4):  ({},{})",r2.0,r2.1);
}
```

I would like the `myquad` routine to work for a variety of floating point types beyond `f32` and `f64`, but also work for them as well.  That said, there's a repeated set of wrappers of the form `Real::from(x)?` where x is a primitive floating point type.  While I understand the need for type consistency, this is somewhat verbose and I have concerns about the manageability of these wrappers for more complicated routines with a lot of primitives.  Is there a better way to handle these conversions or have them work implicitly?  To be sure, the answer may be no, but I'd like to understand this cost before working on more complicated routines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are hitting this roadblock is because you are expecting `num::Float` to be an implemented trait. **It isn't**. Its purpose is as an [extension trait](http://xion.io/post/code/rust-extension-traits.html).

It is implemented for both `f32` and `f64` and allows you to use all the methods it implements on those types without implementing them in the type itself.

That, however, doesn't mean that you can magically add a `T: Float` bound and be out of the woods, however, as your operations require multiplication and subtraction. As such, your constants (as you found out by yourself) need to implement `Sub<X>` and `Mul<X>`, where `X` is the type you have chosen for your constants.

There is, however, a trick. If you know the type of your constants... you can require `From<X>` (where X is the type of your constants). This means you can, at the cost of requiring a *lower bound* on the size of the floats, easily fix this mess.

This lower bound requirement isn't a problem in your case as you are dependent on the `powi` method declared on `num::Float`, and this trait is only implemented for two primitive types: `f32` and `f64`. If you ever wanted to use, say, `half::f16`, you'd need to get rid of the call to `powi`. As such, requiring `f32` as a lower bound is perfectly acceptable.

```
fn myquad<T:Float + From<f32>>(a : T, b: T, c: T) -> Option<(T, T)>
{
    let mysqrt = (b.powi(2) - a * c * (4.0.into())).sqrt();
    let r1 = (-b+mysqrt)/(a * 2.0.into());
    let r2 = (-b-mysqrt)/(a * 2.0.into());
    Some((r1,r2))
}
```

I think that's about as far down as you can go in terms of boilerplate.

Comment: Small correction; if you reverse the order of operations you don't even need the explicit cast!

Comment: Looks good.  Thanks!  For anyone else looking at this, Sebastien is referring to the order of operations for things like `4.0*a*c`.  When written as `a*c*4.0.into()`, type inference allows Rust to determine the correct type for `4.0`'s conversion.  This is not true for `4.0.into()*a*c`, which gives the compiler error, "cannot infer type for T."